# How to resolve blockchain dns using Python Requests

Tags: python, dns, python-requests, blockchain

There are certain blockchain domains that are resolved only by blockchain dns resolvers.

For ex: http://Jstash.bazar

If you try to open this link in a browser, it wont get resolved.

But, just install the browser plugin from https://blockchain-dns.info/
and then try to open the site again, it will open up smoothly.

I want to scrap some data from this site using Python Requests (browserless) and have no idea as to how to resolve such blockchain domains.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of their publicly available apis to resolve the domain and obtain an ip. You'll find a list of [api urls](https://github.com/B-DNS/Firefox/blob/master/common.js#L54) in the Firefox or Chrome addon script, in common.js.
A python example,

```
import requests
from random import choice

def domain_ip(domain):
    '''Uses bdns api to resolve domain names'''
    domain = domain.split('/')[2] if '://' in domain else domain
    apis = ['https://bdns.co/r/', 'https://bdns.us/r/', 'https://bdns.bz/r/']
    api = choice(apis)
    r = requests.get(api+domain)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        ip = r.text.splitlines()[0]
        print("Domain: {}  IP: {}".format(domain, ip))
        return ip
    else:
        print('HTTP Error: {}'.format(r.status_code))

ip = domain_ip('http://jstash.bazar')
if ip:
    r = requests.get('http://'+ip)
```

> Domain: jstash.bazar  IP: 190.115.24.114

---

**Update, 10/20/21**

Bdns is offline and I don't know if they'll be back. I searched for similar public HTTP APIs but couldn't find one that works well enough. Preferably, we can use Dnspython to query an OpenNIC server.

```
import dns.resolver
import requests

def domain_to_ip(domain, dns_server='159.89.120.99'):
    '''Uses an OpenNIC server to resolve blockchain domains   

    :param domain: str Domain or URL  
    :param dns_server: str Optional, OpenNIC server  
    :raises dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: if `dns_server` fails to resolve `domain`
    '''
    if '://' in domain:
        domain = domain.split('/')[2]
        
    res = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    res.nameservers = [dns_server]
    answers = res.resolve(domain)

    return [rdata.address for rdata in answers]


ips = domain_to_ip('http://track2.bazar')
if ips:
    r = requests.get('https://'+ips[0], verify=False)
    print(r)
```

Requires
Dnspython, https://www.dnspython.org/
an OpenNIC `dns_server`, https://servers.opennicproject.org/
and no SSL verification `verify=False`.

Many thanks to @VincentAlex for noticing the issue and proposing a solution.

Comment: It's gone offline https://bdns.io/r/nx.bit

Comment: @VincentAlex Thanks. I've done some research and I found an API from https://www.peername.org/ extension. But it's not that good, it doesn't support .bazar and sometimes it returns HTTP 403. Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: openNIC seems to support most blockchain out of the box, with this lib we could query one dns server (requires IP not domain)
https://pypi.org/project/dnspython/

Comment: @VincentAlex Great idea, thanks again